# Multipling 2 fields using jqyery will return NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:-

```
$("#c1").val(($("#b1").val() * $("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()));
```

where the result should be `75 * 262  = ***` but i got NaN. any advice?

## b1 = 75

while

## Doctor.MedicarePatients = 362

c1 markup `<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="" id="c1" name="c1" value="272">`

b1 markup `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="b1" name="b1" value="75">`

Doctor.MedicarePatients markup `<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Doctor_MedicarePatients" name="Doctor.MedicarePatients" value="362">`

Comment: You should post what the actual contents of the fields are.  The multiplication operator will attempt to coerce the values to numbers, but if there's other stuff in the fields besides valid JavaScript number syntax that process will fail.

Comment: @Pointy updated

Comment: Can you post the actual html of the elements.

Comment: Can you check what `jQuery.type()` returns for `$("#b1").val()` and `$("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()`?

Comment: What **exactly** does the actual HTML look like for those elements?

Comment: @Pointy updated

Comment: @MrGeek updated

Comment: `$("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()` is undefined. It is an incorrect syntax for selector.

Comment: Instead use `$("#Doctor\\.MedicarePatients").val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening as `$("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()` is actually returning `undefined` as we can not have a `.` in the id selector. You will need to escape dot using `\\` to get the actual result.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/):

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: `\\`. For example, an element with `id="foo.bar"`, can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.

**With Error:**

```js
console.log($("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val())
$("#c1").val(($("#b1").val() * $("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="b1" value="259" /><input id="Doctor.MedicarePatients" value="118" /><br/>
<input id="c1" value="" />
```

**Without Error:**

```js
console.log($("#Doctor\\.MedicarePatients").val())
$("#c1").val(($("#b1").val() * $("#Doctor\\.MedicarePatients").val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="b1" value="259" /><input id="Doctor.MedicarePatients" value="118" /><br/>
<input id="c1" value="" />
```

Comment: The updated question shows that the field has `_` instead of the `.` but this is clearly the issue, one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `.` in the selector. In such case read the value as below:

```
$("#c1").val(($("#b1").val() * $("#Doctor\\.MedicarePatients").val()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code was this snippet `$("#Doctor.MedicarePatients").val()`, the problem was the id of the input element was **Doctor_MedicarePatients**, but you were selecting the wrong one with **.**(Dot), so it return undefined.

So the calculation was happening as `undefined * 75` which returned as NaN

See the below updated code.

```js
$("#c1").val($("#b1").val() * $("#Doctor_MedicarePatients").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled="" id="c1" name="c1" value="272">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="b1" name="b1" value="75">

<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="Doctor_MedicarePatients" name="Doctor.MedicarePatients" value="362">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a fallback option if the value of your input is not a number. You can use parseFloat or parseInt then add " || 0" at the end.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var first_number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("first-number").value) || 0;
  var second_number = parseFloat(document.getElementById("second-number").value) || 0;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = first_number * second_number;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<input id="first-number" type="text">
<input id="second-number" type="text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
```